# How to scale a gameObject with pinch?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

How do I scale gameObject (cube) with a pinch (2 fingers) in Android/iOS?. If the pinch is expanding, then the cube's scale (x, y, z) gets bigger and if the pinch is closing down, then the cube's scale gets smaller.

I have a script that was for mouse drag but only scales for 2 axis (x, y).

```
public class Drag : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 lastMousePosition;
    float scaleSensitivity = 2f;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
         }
         if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
             transform.localScale += ((Input.mousePosition - lastMousePosition) * Time.deltaTime * scaleSensitivity);
             lastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at Input.Touches : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html  and use difference (Input.Touches[0] - Input.Touches[1]).magnitude, fixing every frame that difference. If it's becoming bigger with every frame, that means user is scaling up, else if it's becoming smaller, that means user is scaling down.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Input.Touches : [Input.Touches](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touches.html)  and use difference `(Input.Touches[0] - Input.Touches[1]).magnitude`, fixing every frame that difference. If it's becoming bigger with every frame, that means user is scaling up, else if it's becoming smaller, that means user is scaling down

```
float? _prevFrameDiff;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touches.Length < 2)
    {
        _prevFrameDiff = null;
        return;
    }

    var diff = (Input.touches[0].position - Input.touches[1].position).magnitude;

    if (!_prevFrameDiff.HasValue)
    {
        _prevFrameDiff = diff;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var scaleFactor = diff / _prevFrameDiff.Value;

        this.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * scaleFactor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks but unfortunately it does not register the last position of the touch. How do I do this?